# Feature class field count caching issue

Tags: cache, arcscene, update, fields-attributes, feature-class

In our application, we exposed a custom file format to ArcScene through a custom plugin data-source.
However, we experience some problems which we ascribe to caching issues.

We generate a dataset with 5 fields, in particular OID, Shape and 3 custom columns. This dataset is added
to the scene through a standard feature layer. ArcScene properly calls **IPlugInDatasetHelper.get_Fields** to obtain the **IFields** from our dataset.

Upon user interaction, this dataset might get regenerated where the number of fields might change.
In this case to OID, Shape and a single custom row.
If ArcScene now calls **IPlugInDatasetHelper.FetchAll** ,
the last parameter (**object FieldMap**) still contains 5 entries. ArcScene does not call **IPlugInDatasetHelper.get_Fields** anymore, despite the column count having changed.

Is there a way to tell ArcScene/ArcMap the fields in our custom data-source have changed?

We already tried ISceneGraph.Invalidate on our feature layer or ActiveView.Redraw of no avail.

Thanks!